# create page layout with page fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, page-layout

I have created a page layout usign the design manager and i associated to a specific conrent type. It works well.
so, using the SharePoint designer, on the html file of the page Layout ,I reorganise my Snippet fields and i added some static values, in order to find them in pageLayout after.

but I'm surprised that my page layout only contain the Snippet fields and without  values ?

So any idea how have those values , here is some code:

```
<label class="metaFooterDescription" ID="Label4" runat="server">
            <div>
                <!--CS: Start Page Field: Button Text Snippet-->
                <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldTextField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                <!--MS:<PageFieldTextField:TextField FieldName="792a58e3-5bb6-4dae-8bad-cf72d985e95d" runat="server">-->
                <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)-->
                <div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Button Text</span></div>
                <div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"> there texxxxxtx to show bla bla bla </div></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
                <!--ME:</PageFieldTextField:TextField>-->
                <!--CE: End Page Field: Button Text Snippet-->
            </div>

        </label>
```

when i go to the aspx of the pageLayout,i only have the snipped code , with no values :

```
<label class="metaFooterDescription" ID="Label4" runat="server">
            <div>


                <PageFieldTextField:TextField FieldName="792a58e3-5bb6-4dae-8bad-cf72d985e95d" runat="server">

                </PageFieldTextField:TextField>

            </div>

        </label>
```

and when i create a page with this pageLayout, also no way to have the value which added to html part .

So is there a way to have a page Layout full withvalue? like text , images ...